# is subset W a subspace of V?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to determine whether the subset W is a subspace of V. Assume V has the standard operations.
W is the set of all 3 x 2 matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\a-2b & 0\\0 & c\end{bmatrix}$. V = M(3,2).
Have I approached this correctly? My attempt:[image]

Comment: You can also recognize that $W$ is the span of $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-2&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I think that your approach is correct

Comment: Thanks guys. I think ive figured it out then.